# Using requirejs and trying to optimize javascript into a vendor file and an app file

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, code-organization

I'm working on a project using requirejs and I'm trying to optimize my javascript into two files: vendor libraries and app code. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work.

**Folder structure:**

- backbone_components/
- app/

  - less/
  - js/

    - component1/
    - component2/
    - layouts/

      - dashboard/
      - about/
    - lib/
    - config.js
    - main.js
  - index.html
- dist/
- Gruntfile.js

**config.js:**

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '../js/',
  paths: {
    jquery:     '../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
    underscore: '../../bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash',
    backbone:   '../../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
    text:       '../../bower_components/requirejs-text/text'
  },
  enforeceDefine: true
});

define(['backbone', 'main'], function(Backbone, app) {
});
```

**Gruntfile.js:**

```
requirejs: {
  options: {
    dir: 'dist/js/',
    mainConfigFile: 'app/js/config.js',
    optimize: 'none', 
    normalizeDirDefines: 'all',
    skipDirOptimize: true
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      modules: [
        {
          name: 'vendor',
          include: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text'],
        },
        {
          name: 'app',
          exclude: ['vendor']
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

---

When I run `grunt`, I get the following error: "Error: Error: ERROR: module path does not exist: /path/to/project/app/js/app/js/vendor.js for module named: vendor."

Why is it looking for "vendor" when it doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that you have no module named `vendor` in the source you want to optimize. If this is correct, then the error you are getting is because `r.js` *is* looking for a module named `vendor`. You have to tell it to *create* it with the `create` option:

```
modules: [
    {
      name: 'vendor',
      create: true,            // <--- Add this option!
      include: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text']
    },
    {
      name: 'app',
      exclude: ['vendor']
    }
]
```

Without the option `r.js` understands you to be effectively saying "take the `vendor` module and include with it `jquery`, etc." With the option, you are telling it to create `vendor` from scratch.

The `create` option is documented [in this file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js).

Comment: Thanks Louis. I was just reading about "create" when your comment came in. And that made it work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, all javascript files are being copied into "dist/js". I expected only vendor.js and main.js to be there. Did I miss something else?

Comment: `removeCombined: true` I would think. You can find it documented in the same file as `create`.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Would of expected `removeCombined`'s default to be true. Feeling better about this. Thanks again.